# What does "object allocation during garbage collection phase" in my Rails log mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to run a Rails app on IBM Bluemix and load test it with Blitz.io.  When I access the app in my browser, everything is fine.  When Blitz tries to access it, however, the app crashes.  The log entry looks like this:

```
2014-12-20T16:26:45.55-0500 [RTR]     OUT **[my app name]**.mybluemix.net -     [20/12/2014:21:26:43+0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12784 "-" "blitz.io; e970e720c4f22c94f7d822731652a745@130.160.6.54" 75.126.70.42:54311 x_forwarded_for:"-" vcap_request_id:ba32f5d0-e157-4229-61f5-13eb7ab3d2d0 response_time:2.182336949 app_id:1e6ad01b-c7b4-4f57-8d9d-8d333807bb15

2014-12-20T16:26:46.60-0500 [App/0]   ERR /home/vcap/app/vendor/ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:284: [BUG] object allocation during garbage collection phase
```

What does this mean?  I'm at a bit of a loss on how to debug this, or even where the problem lies.  Is it a problem with my app code?  A configuration problem?

I'm not sure whether I've included enough of the error log to be helpful here.  The rest is here:

http://pastebin.com/Jv6jUksv

Comment: According to https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9090 this was reported and fixed on ruby 2.1.0.dev; the log shows you are using ruby 2.0.0; try using 2.1.5 ruby.

Comment: Unfortunately, Bluemix doesn't seem to support ruby versions above 2.0.0.  I tried rolling back to 1.9.3.  I no longer receive this exact error message, but the crash remains.  Maybe I need to look into a different hosting platform.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the Ruby version you want to run in your applications in the Gem file. The Ruby buildpack in Bluemix supports Ruby v2.1.x, v2.2 and more.

But I guess the possible cause of the error is that your app is exceeding the memory quota that's allocated to your application. Bluemix is using CloudFoundry, which will kill the app instance if it consumes more memories than allocated. You can increase the memory allocated to your application by specifying the "-m" option when you do "cf push". For example:

```
cf push -m 1G
```

Answer (score 0):

you can raise ticket/ask question in developer forum on bluemix support for speedy resolution

of this issue(if ruby 2.0.0 is having issue and if advance version of the same is working fine

for you):

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way you can see the memory usage around the time of this error message?

I've gotten the error

> [BUG] object allocation during garbage collection phase

using Ruby 1.8.7 in an environment with explicit memory restrictions (probably similar to that of IBM Bluemix) when exceeding those memory restrictions. My memory is limited by a [PBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Batch_System) directive.

For me, the error occurs when parsing a large amount of JSON where the json gem requires more memory than the limit for this particular JSON string.